# Scraping all text using Scrapy without knowing webpages' structure

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am conducting a research which relates to distributing the indexing of the internet.

While several such projects exist (IRLbot, Distributed-indexing, Cluster-Scrapy, Common-Crawl etc.), mine is more focused on incentivising such behavior.  I am looking for a simple way to crawl real webpages without knowing anything about their URL or HTML structure and:

1. extract all their text (in order to index it)
2. Collect all their URLs and add them to the URLs to crawl
3. Prevent crashing and elegantly continuing (even without the scraped text) in case of malformed webpage

To clarify - this is only for Proof of Concept (PoC), so I don't mind it won't scale, it's slow, etc. I am aiming at scraping most of the text which is presented to the user, in most cases, with or without dynamic content, and with as little "garbage" such as functions, tags, keywords etc. A working simple partial solution which works out of the box is preferred over the perfect solution which requires a lot of expertise to deploy.

A secondary issue is the storing of the (url,extracted text) for indexing (by a different process?), but I think I will be able to figure it out myself with some more digging.

Any advice on how to augment "itsy"'s parse function will be highly appreciated!

```html
import scrapy

from scrapy_1.tutorial.items import WebsiteItem


class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'itsy'

# allowed_domains = ['dmoz.org'] 

start_urls = \
    [
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    ]

# def parse(self, response):
#     filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
#     with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
#         f.write(response.body)

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = WebsiteItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['body_text'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Why are you only searching li's if you want all the text, links etc? `body_text` seems like you want all the text in the body but you are only searching the li so that does not really make a lot of sense. As far as storing goes you probably want a database which is a complete topic in itself and should be a separate question.

Comment: Because I don't know any better when it comes to CSS/HTML/XPath. As far as I understand, there are all sorts of sorted and unsorted items in "div"s and "a"s, and I should somehow collect them all. This was what I was able to gather so far from online examples which were tailored to specific websites.

Comment: What do you consider text? `"body//text()"` would get all the text from the body but that would also include Js functions etc.. `("body//a")` would get all the anchors, a `try/except` would handle any errors. You really need to narrow down what it is exactly that you want.

Comment: Text is every word in the webpage's HTML. I'd rather ignore "href", "div" and other tags/commands/keywords, butI will take them in if I have to. In a perfect world, I would get every text word that the user see. In an awesome world, I would get every text word the user see which is in included in the HTML. In a good world, I will get every word in the HTML, including a few words which belong to the HTML structure but are hard to filter out.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - thanks for your input. regarding the 'try/except', I was hoping to be able to extract some of the text from malformed/problematic websites (I think beautifulsoup is capable of doing this), however attempting to do this myself is prone to fail in all sort of weird corner-cases.

Comment: What about dynamic content?

Comment: It's an excellent question. I **think** I would rather ignore it, but again, as this is a PoC, both with and without it will work, so it depends on how complicated it is to get/avoid it. To clarify - my first priority is to make it work. I now understand there are many factors that needs to be narrowed down, however for my purpose I will take any solution which works one way or another.

Comment: Well you will need something like Selenium or scrapy-splash that can run Js if you want dynamically created content, it will also be a hell of a lot slower to go down this route, even more so as you may need to add a wait to make sure the content has fully loaded.

Comment: In that case - I don't want the dynamic content. for PoC purposes, I just want a solution which brings most of the text in most cases and without most of the commands/tags/JS functions/etc. I will edit the original question to clarify this point.

Comment: Something like `"//body//*[not(name()='script')]//text()""` would ignore all script tags but you may find creating a set of tags to ignore and then visit each node and only extract text from those who's name is not in the exclusion set

Comment: If we took this page as an example what would you consider text?

Comment: This page should yield all the text in my question and in the comments. It can also yield the text in the tabs above ("Questions", "Jobs",etc) and the "Asked/ viewd" "Related", "Hot Network Questions", all the text at the bottom (about us , tou, help, blog...)

Comment: This is a simple example of getting all text where no ancestor is a script or noscript tag and getting all hrefs from the body http://pastebin.com/tRUGmJ4Q,  you can get way more specific filtering out more tags but the reality is there is no silver bullet that will give you the optimum solution for every page maybe bar you using AI,  also not everyone who writes html is does it for a living and some markup is just terrible and terribly broken.

Comment: Much appreciated :) Once I will have my PoC reasonably running I'll publish my working solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for here is scrapy [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider)

CrawlSpider lets you define crawling rules that are followed for every page. It's smart enough to avoid crawling images, documents and other files that are not web resources and it pretty much does the whole thing for you.

Here's a good example how your spider might look with CrawlSpider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawlspider'
    start_urls = ['http://scrapy.org']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.meta['link_text']
        # extracting basic body
        item['body'] = '\n'.join(response.xpath('//text()').extract())
        # or better just save whole source
        item['source'] = response.body
        return item
```

This spider will crawl every webpage it can find on the website and log the title, url and whole text body.
For text body you might want to extract it in some smarter way(to exclude javascript and other unwanted text nodes), but that's an issue on it's own to discuss.
Actually for what you are describing you probably want to save full html source rather than text only, since unstructured text is useless for any sort of analitics or indexing.

There's also bunch of scrapy settings that can be adjusted for this type of crawling. It's very nicely described in [Broad Crawl docs page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I might try to combine it with the solution @Padaric 's example. Do you mind providing a **short** explanation about the Rule you have added? Thanks again! P.S. I will mark it as "answered" once I test it this afternoon...

Comment: @UriCS The rule I used is very basic. It takes basic `LinkExtractor` which extracts all web page links, makes a request and callsback `parse_item` method on them. The `follow=True` argument means that every link extracted by this extractor should also be followed with the same rule so this cycle continues until LinkExtractor finds no links or all of those links have been visited (scrapy automatically keeps track of all visitied links and by default ignores duplicates). So essentially it crawls the entire webpage :)