# Using Scrapy to scrape * URLs

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am new to using Scrapy and I would like to use it to do a test scrape on http://www.forums.mlb.com/discussions/Major_League_Baseball/ml-mlb?redirCnt=1.

I would like to pull all 'a' elements with attribute 'href' containing the term "white sox" using the following XPath: $x('//a[contains(@href, "white sox")]') from the **entire message board**.

Can the community assist with what URL I should input into the "Start URL" variable within my first spider class to crawl the whole message board?

I am new to web scraping so forgive me.

Bud

Comment: URLs don't have any concept like a "wildcard".

Comment: I guess this would also be a good resource to follow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154393/scraping-all-text-using-scrapy-without-knowing-webpages-structure. Looks like linke extractor and crawlspider are the way to go?

Comment: Still waiting for some guidance here. Just an FYI I want to make sure I only parse hrefs and h1's containing "white sox"